# Laravel: Update data without select file again

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a table called projects with this fields:

**TABLE INFORMATION**

id, slug, order, public, pathheader and pathhome.

**CREATE VIEW**

The form to store the data looks like this:

```
<div id="formcreateproject">
        <form  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myFormProject" name="myFormProject">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label name="title">Slug:</label>
            <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="ejemplo-de-slug" class="form-control form-control-sm"><br>
      <!--      <label name="order">Order:</label>
            <input type="number" id="order" name="order" class="form-control form-control-sm">-->
            <!--<label name="public">Public:</label>-->
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                      <img src="" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;" onerror="this.src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII='">
                      <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader"  class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <img src="" id="img2" class="img2" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;" onerror="this.src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII='">
                      <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;"><br>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                      <input type="button" name="" value="Seleccionar header" id="browse_file" class="btn btn-danger form-control">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input type="button" name="" value="Seleccionar home" id="browse_file2" class="btn btn-danger form-control">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Crear Proyecto" id="createprojectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
            <br><br><br>

          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
```

**FUNCTION TO SAVE THE DATA**

And the function looks like this:

```
 public function storeProject(Request $request)
        {

        $project = new Project();
        $project->slug = $request->input("slug");
        //$project->order = $request->input("order");
        $project->order = DB::table('projects')
                      ->where('order', DB::raw("(select max(`order`) from projects)"))
                      ->first()
                      ->order + 1; 
        $project->public = 0;
        $project->pathheader = $request->file('pathheader');
        $project->pathhome = $request->file('pathhome');

        \Storage::disk('projects')->makeDirectory($project->slug);
        \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathheader,'header.jpg');
        \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathhome,'home.jpg');
        $project->save();
        }
```

This works really good, and save me values like: /tmp/phQX0ddm in pathheader and pathhome.

**VIEW TO UPDATE THE DATA**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label><strong>Slug</strong></label>
                  <textarea type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="slug" name="slug" rows="1" required style="resize:none;">{{$project->slug}}</textarea>
              </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label><strong>Order</strong></label>
                      <textarea type="number" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="order" name="order" rows="1">{{$project->order}}</textarea>
                </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label><strong>Public</strong></label>
                <textarea type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="public" name="public" value="" rows="1">{{$project->public}}</textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
           <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                      @if (Storage::disk('projects')->has($project->slug))
                      <img src="{{ asset('/storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/header.jpg') }}" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
                      @else
                      <img src="" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
                      @endif
                      <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      @if (Storage::disk('projects')->has($project->slug))
                      <img src="{{ asset('/storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/home.jpg') }}" id="img" class="img" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
                      @else
                      <img src="" id="img2" class="img2" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:#ccc;border:2px solid gray;">
                      @endif
                      <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp" style="display:none;"><br>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                      <input type="button" name="" value="Seleccionar header" id="browse_file" class="btn btn-danger form-control">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <input type="button" name="" value="Seleccionar home" id="browse_file2" class="btn btn-danger form-control">
                  </td>
                </tr>
     </table>
```

**FUNCTION TO UPDATE THE DATA**

```
public function updateProject(Request $request, $id) 

//Actualizar la informacion de un trabajador
    {
        $project = Project::find($id);
        $project->slug = $request->input('slug');
        $project->order = $request->input('order');
        $project->public = $request->input('public');
        if($request->hasFile('pathheader')){
            $project->pathheader = $request->file('pathheader');
            \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathheader,'header.jpg');
        }
        $project->pathheader = Project::find($id)->pathheader;
        if($request->hasFile('pathhome')){
            $project->pathhome = $request->file('pathhome');
            \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathhome,'home.jpg');
        }
        $project->pathhome = Project::find($id)->pathhome;
        $project->save();
    }
```

The problem is, if I don't select again the file when I update the data, image isn't loaded.

How can I fix this? My first idea was take the value of pathhome and pathheader and put it on function controller to update the data again with same values, but doesn't work.

I hope someone can help me, I will be really really appreciated.

Comment: Hi @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I have this other query: ` $employee->order = DB::table('workers')
                      ->where('order', DB::raw("(select max(`order`) from workers)"))
                      ->first()
                      ->order + 1; ` and works!

Comment: try DB::table('projects')->where('id',$id)->value('pathheader');

Comment: `DB::table('projects')->select('pathheader')->where('id',$id)->get()`;

Comment: `DB::raw("select ('pathheader') from projects)")` ? there's an extra closing parenthesis right after `projects)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Project model like:

```
$pathheader = Project::find($id)->pathheader;
```

Comment: Hi Matei, this works. Anyway, maybe you can help me. I will edit the question and put more information, wait a few minuts.

Comment: Updated! Check it please

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer you can't set the file path to the FILE input as it is a security risk. When update you should display the image or file separately and put there an delete link. If a new file is selected in the input then you delete the existing one and upload the new one..

Comment: Check if you can my new question. I try to make the question simple and just put the code I think people need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615263/laravel-delete-folder-and-save-data

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this :

```
$project->pathheader = DB::table('projects')
                            ->where('id',$id)
                            ->where('pathheader',  DB::raw("(select pathheader from projects)"))
                            ->first();
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: Check the question again please

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer Sure

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
$pathheader = DB::table('projects')->select('pathheader')->where('id','=',$id)‌​->first();
```

I think this is what you seeking for

Comment: Check the question again please