# Laravel: Delete folder and save data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a function where I pass some data, slug, order, public, and two images.

If I have on request 'slug' I want to delete the folder called with the last project->slug and create the new one.

Something like that:

```
if ($request->has('slug'))
    {
            \Storage::disk('projects')->deleteDirectory($project->slug);
            \Storage::disk('projects')->makeDirectory($project->slug);
    }
```

And save inside the image, and if I don't select a new image, save the last image that project Have, with something like this:

```
       if($request->hasFile('pathheader')){
            $project->pathheader = $request->file('pathheader');
            \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathheader,'header.jpg');
        }
        $project->pathheader = Project::find($id)->pathheader;
        if($request->hasFile('pathhome')){
            $project->pathhome = $request->file('pathhome');
            \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug,$project->pathhome,'home.jpg');
        }
        $project->pathhome = Project::find($id)->pathhome;
        $project->save();
```

How can I do it? I'm stuck with this..

I will really appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot.

**DELETE FOLDER DONE**

Just change some lines, now code looks like here:

```
if ($request->has('slug')) {
            \Storage::disk('projects')->deleteDirectory($project->slug);
        }
        $project->slug = $request->input('slug');
        \Storage::disk('projects')->makeDirectory($project->slug);
```